# sending email without MessageUI

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I was wondering if there is any way of sending emails with attachments other then using MessageUI in iOs.

The thing is that I have a class that is conflicting with the Account class in that framework and I'll be damned if I'm going to rewrite a ton of code and change the core data model risking problems with the app update just because they were stupid enough to use common names for their classes.

I'm new to objective c so I never thought about the namespace problem because in my opinion frameworks should do that not the programmer, its the first time that I cant give a common name to a class because the SDK uses it... and from what I read that framework gives this headache to a lot of people because of class names like Account, Message, Connection.

Anyway, is there any alternative out there?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

there's no such facility in the iOS SDK, as this would risk some malicious programmers to spam users. However, you can try this mailing library a developer made and ported for iOS:
https://github.com/dinhviethoa/libetpan

Comment: Would apple even approve this? Something telle me that they might frown on this...

Comment: That's cool, then. I was just worried they might not like it, but from the sounds of it, it's OK.